# Make child page active when clicked from google

Tags: jquery, css, cookies

I have got a working vertical accordion menu that creates an active class and saves when moving from page to page throughout the website. The problem I have is that when I go to a child page from google for example, the accordion menu won't drop down and show that active class.

I am using cookies to save the class when going from page to page. Will I use a similar technique to capture the page that it's on when searching from google?

http://jsfiddle.net/tebrown/uzrbbqx9/4/

```
    $('#cssmenu > li:has(ul)').addClass("has-sub");

    var checkCookie = $.cookie("nav-item");
    if (checkCookie != "") {
        $('#cssmenu > li > a:eq(' + checkCookie + ')').addClass('active').next().show();
    }
    checkCookie = $.cookie("sub_nav-item");
    if (checkCookie != "") {
        $('#cssmenu > li > ul > li > a:eq(' + checkCookie + ')').addClass('active').next().show();
    }


    $('#cssmenu > li > ul > li > a').click(function () {
        var navIndex = $('#cssmenu > li > ul > li > a').index(this);
        $.cookie("sub_nav-item", navIndex);
        var checkElement = $(this).next();


        $(this).removeClass('testing');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('testing');
        $('#cssmenu li li .active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    $('#cssmenu > li > a').click(function () {
        var $a = $(this),
            $ul = $a.next(),
            navIndex = $('#cssmenu > li > a').index(this);

        $.cookie("nav-item", navIndex);
        $('#cssmenu li a.active').not(this).removeClass('active').next().stop().slideUp();

        if ($ul.is(':animated'))
            return;

        $ul.stop().slideToggle();
        $a.toggleClass('active');

        });
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Can you elaborate on (when I go to a child page from google) what do you mean by that? Are you using Iframes or something?

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus on 3 solutions:

### Cookie

The worst solution for me. It has many contentious situation:

- Assume that we are on page A, then we use menu to go page B (still works fine). What's when we use another link (outside menu) to go back to page A?
- We visit the page from google or just change the url in browser - how we detect the active page?

### Window location

Detect active menu entry by comparing the url (window.location == a[href]).

Better, but...

- We can have page that don't have the same url as menu link href, but it's still the sub-page of this section. Again - how to detect it?

### Hardcoded

Defining active menu item in every view.

The best solution, but can also be a pain if done in the wrong way.

---

### The answer

Going back to your question - you can combine last 2 methods. Just take pages url (part of window location solution) and create something like "website map" (part of last solution, but there you define it in one js file):

```
{
    'url_1': 'active_menu_item',
    'url_2': 'another_active_menu_item',
    'maybe_some_[regexp]+`: '???',
    ...
}
```

or define these variables (`checkCookie` and e.q. `checkCookieSub`) at the top of view.

So where are the cookies? Sorry, I can't find a way how to improve this cookie method (we can navigate over the site in so many ways, they are useless and most painful) :)

Comment: Hi @r4xz thanks for reply. The cookies are stored in a external file. If you go to the jsfiddle link you will see the external resources file location. So to detect active menu I will need to run a wondow.location to see if it will match the current page?

Comment: Yes, http://jsfiddle.net/14hp70ef/3/ see the difference when you click F5 and Run.